# Selendroid Selenium android (sencha extjs) test couldn't find element

Tags: java, android, selenium

I am trying to run a test on my android device and using Selenium Webdriver with Java. Currently, only the .apk is started. Selendroid Inspector can not load properties. Its showing loading progress bar and not able to load web element viewer.
Relevant login system code:

```
'Ext.define('TutorialApp.view.login.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    xtype: 'login',

    requires: [
        'TutorialApp.view.login.LoginController',
        'Ext.form.Panel'
    ],

    controller: 'login',
    bodyPadding: 10,
    title: 'Login Window',
    closable: false,
    autoShow: true,

    items: {
        xtype: 'form',
        reference: 'form',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'username',
            fieldLabel: 'Username',
            allowBlank: false
        }, {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'password',
            inputType: 'password',
            fieldLabel: 'Password',
            allowBlank: false
        }, {
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            hideEmptyLabel: false,
            value: 'Enter any non-blank password'
        }],
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Login',
            formBind: true,
            listeners: {
                click: 'onLoginClick'
            }
        }]
    }
});
```

Here is my code:

```
import io.selendroid.SelendroidCapabilities;
import io.selendroid.SelendroidConfiguration;
import io.selendroid.SelendroidDriver;
import io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher;
import io.selendroid.device.DeviceTargetPlatform;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class NewTest {​
private WebDriver driver;

@BeforeSuite
public void setUp() throws Exception {
SelendroidConfiguration config = new SelendroidConfiguration();
config.addSupportedApp("test.apk");
SelendroidLauncher selendroidServer = new SelendroidLauncher(config);
selendroidServer.launchSelendroid();
SelendroidCapabilities capa = new SelendroidCapabilities();
capa.setAut("de.bgk:1.0.4");
capa.setPlatformVersion(DeviceTargetPlatform.ANDROID19);
capa.setEmulator(false);
driver = new SelendroidDriver(capa);
}

@Test
public void selendroidTest() throws Exception {​
System.out.print("Start executing test");
Thread.sleep(10000);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("username")));
driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("user");
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("password");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login")).click();
}

@AfterSuite
public void tearDown() {
driver.quit();
}
}​
```

How can I solve this problem in Selendroid with Java? Will be grateful for any help.